# Rails 4 Facebook authentication with Devise and Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, devise, omniauth-facebook

I'm trying to implement authentication from Facebook in my app, for a Customer model. I had already done an authentication for Customers with Devise.
I had followed [this guide](http://willschenk.com/setting-up-devise-with-twitter-and-facebook-and-other-omniauth-schemes-without-email-addresses/).
In the initializer devise.rb I added this row:

```
config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'], scope: "email"
```

This is my Customer model:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :omniauthable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable #, :validatable

validates_presence_of :name

validates_uniqueness_of :nickname

before_save :complete_nickname

def complete_nickname
  if !self.nickname?
    self.nickname = self.email
  end
end

def facebook
  identities.where( :provider => "facebook" ).first
end

def facebook_client
  @facebook_client ||= Facebook.client( access_token: facebook.accesstoken )
end
end
```

This is my Identity model, written as specified in the guide:

```
class Identity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer

  validates_presence_of :uid, :provider
  validates_uniqueness_of :uid, :scope => :provider

  def self.find_for_oauth(auth)
    identity = find_by(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid)
    identity = create(uid: auth.uid, provider: auth.provider) if identity.nil?
    identity.accesstoken = auth.credentials.token
    identity.refreshtoken = auth.credentials.refresh_token
    identity.name = auth.info.name
    identity.email = auth.info.email
    identity.nickname = auth.info.name.gsub(/\s+/, "")
    identity.image = auth.info.image
    identity.phone = auth.info.phone
    identity.urls = (auth.info.urls || "").to_json
    identity.save
    identity
  end
end
```

This is my OmniauthCallbackController

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    generic_callback( 'facebook' )
  end

  def generic_callback( provider )
    @identity = Identity.find_for_oauth env["omniauth.auth"]

    @customer = @identity.customer || current_customer
    if @customer.nil?
      @customer = Customer.create( email: @identity.email || "", nickname: @identity.email || "" )
      @identity.update_attribute( :customer_id, @customer.id )
    end  

    if @customer.email.blank? && @identity.email
      @customer.update_attribute( :email, @identity.email)
    end

    if @customer.persisted?
      @identity.update_attribute( :customer_id, @customer.id )
      # This is because we've created the user manually, and Device expects a
      # FormUser class (with the validations)
      @customer = FormUser.find @customer.id
      sign_in_and_redirect @customer, event: :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: provider.capitalize) if is_navigational_format?
      else
        session["devise.#{provider}_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]
        redirect_to new_customer_registration_url
      end
    end
  end
```

When I click on Login in with Facebook I am not authenticated, and the app redirects me on the login form. 
On the server outuput I see that it tried to create a Customer, but then it fails and rollbacks:

```
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "identities" SET "accesstoken" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "identities"."id" = $3  [["accesstoken", "CAABtFtDqAlwBAEFzpAtw2W2gUTLkpKbtjI4lqKibkIO5kyJSwNYK9TDzDG4NfEoq40oQdUzXxZADRZBwYy319KPobEU6378ULwQ3PtKT46EbEugs4eIdsQyfZC3S8yLIJoPW6uq7ZAF0AnEeepDvl97ajbazsmGsuP22rnK0G1zSTHzoBfPpGZAD4NkgW7Kp5r5TiLhxxEgZDZD"], ["updated_at", "2015-11-24 11:18:28.010402"], ["id", 2]]
  (65.7ms)  COMMIT
  (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Customer Exists (4.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "customers" WHERE  "customers"."nickname" = '' LIMIT 1
  (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Maybe it's a validation control that I already had on my Customer object, but I can't figure out what it can be.
This is the schema of my Customer:

```
  create_table "customers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                   default: "",   null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",      default: "",   null: false
    t.string   "name",                    default: "",   null: false
    t.string   "surname",                 default: "",   null: false
    t.string   "nickname",                default: "",   null: false
    ...
  end
```

Someone can help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: I think my problem is that Facebook doesn't return an email, but I specified email as scope in devise initializer

Answer (score 0):

Try to this configuration

devise.rb

```
config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'], scope: 'email', info_fields: 'email, name'
```

Comment: Yes thanks! Now I have an email! I put a space betweeb email and name, for this it didn't work. it doens't authenticate yet but now I have an email address

Answer (score 0):

I solved, it seems to work with my Facebook account.
I update the omniauth-facebook gem, that maybe was part of the issue, with `bundle update omniauth-facebook`. I modified the initializer devise.rb in this way (no spaces in scope and info_fields):

```
`config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'], scope: "email,public_profile", info_fields: 'email,name,first_name,last_name'`
```

And modified the OmniauthCallbackController:

```
@customer = Customer.create( email: @identity.email || "", nickname: @identity.nickname || "", 
  name: env["omniauth.auth"]["info"]["first_name"] || "", 
  surname: env["omniauth.auth"]["info"]["last_name"] || "",
  password: "********", password_confirmation: "********" )
  @identity.update_attribute( :customer_id, @customer.id )
```

Because in my Customer model name and surname are mandatory fields.
I still have a problem. I pushed the app on Heroku and I can sign in with my Facebook account and with other users accounts, but for some other users Facebook doesn't return the email.